# Return value of child_process in terminal

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, python-3.7

How can I return a value of an python child process, which I have started through the `main.py` by following code:

```
subprocess.check_output(['lxterminal -e  python3 rfid_input.py'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, close_fds=True)
```

**parent process:**

```
import sys, subprocess
value = subprocess.check_output(['lxterminal -e  python3 rfid_input.py'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, close_fds=True)
print(value)
```

The **child process** contains a simple `x=input()` and looks like following:

```
import sys
x=input()
sys.stdout.write(x)
```

but Ii still receive nothing else as the empty `b''`.

I also tried it by `subprocess.Popen` with `.wait()` and `.communicate()` with no success.

If you have any other ideas how I can get the value of the lxterminal input, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

For passing data to stdin, your setting would usually look like this

```
import subprocess

stdin = b"THE DATA YOU PASS"
terminal = subprocess.Popen(["lxterminal", "-e", "python3", "rfid_input.py"],
                            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = terminal.communicate(stdin)
```

When you call `.communicate` without arguments, it usually passes empty bytes, that might be what happened here.

Template example:

Parent:

```
import subprocess

stdin = b"THE DATA YOU PASS"
terminal = subprocess.Popen(["python3", "stackoverflow_child.py"],
                            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = terminal.communicate(stdin)
print(stdout.decode("utf-8"), stderr.decode("utf-8"))
```

child with name `stackoverflow_child.py`:

```
import sys
x=input()
sys.stdout.write(x * 2)  # so you can see the child was called
```

If you don't want to handle bytes, you can also pass `encoding="utf-8"` to Popen, then you can pass stdin as string and receive stdout and stderr as strings.